# Find the number of good swaps.

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle, integer-partitions

Suppose we are given a positive integer N. Consider the sequence S=(1,2,…,N). You should choose two elements of this sequence and swap them.A swap is nice if there is an integer M (1≤M<N) such that the sum of the first M elements of the resulting sequence is equal to the sum of its last N−M elements. What is the number of nice swaps.

Comment: Add your attempts to your question thats better.

Comment: This question is part of the [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT20A/problems/CHFNSWAP) September Challenge, and has been locked in accordance with the Math SE contest policy.